# Overriding styles upon :hover

Tags: css, hover

I'm creating a Inbox in which there will me a asp menu on the side and Inbox on the center. I need to change the font color to red and make it bold when I see a new row from the database. I have used `adding` on the menu item.

If Not Hovered it looks like this.

[image: When New Item is found in Database]

If Hovered It Has to look like this.

[image: hovered appearance]

But the problem is that when I hover on the text it looks like the image shown above, but if I hover slightly on the top or bottom of the menuItenm (Inside the Menu Item but not on Text), Then This looks like this.

[image: just off hover]

CSS used For Menu Item.

```
.Menu ul li a {
color: black;
background: #E9E9E9;
display: block;
padding: 5px 0;
line-height: 17px;
padding-left: 8px; /*link text is indented 8px*/
text-decoration: none;}

.Menu ul li a:hover{
background-image: none;
color: white;
background: #424242;}
```

Here is the code I used to change The color and set the font to bold From server side.

```
Menu1.Items[0].Text = "<div class='inboxno' >" + "Inbox (" + (i + 1) + ")" + "</div>";
```

Here is the CSS class of inbox.

```
.inboxno{
background-image: none;
color: Red;
font-weight:bold;}

.inboxno:hover{
background-image: none;
color: white;
background: #424242;
font-weight:bold;}
```

I think I understand the problem. It is, that a `<DIV>` is created around the inbox Text inside the Menu Item and It has the Css inboxno. But the Menu Item has padding and When I place mouse on the padding Area then the inboxno:hover class is not being applied to the Div.

I think one of the solutions to this problem is, if I could access the  `.Menu ul li a` class from `.inboxno:hover` class I will remove the Padding Property and Set the Same padding property in the `.inboxno:hover` class.

But I don't know how to access the `.Menu ul li a` class from `.inboxno:hover` class.

Can you Help me??

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you're just asking about the hover or not but try doing

```
.Menu ul li:hover a {
    background-image: none;
    color: white;
    background: #424242;
}
```

Comment: I need to apply the css class from the server side only when I found a new item in DB. Is it possible to remove a css property from server side??

Comment: No but you can be crafty and try something like adding a class with the bold styling to the first table element (inboxno?) for only a second or two and remove it via javascript after the time expired.

Comment: This is basically for demonstration of the concept http://jsfiddle.net/seany789/CGySc/4/